# Replacing Spaces with Underscores

Tags: php

I have a PHP Script that users will enter a name like: `Alex_Newton`,

However, some users will use a space rather than an underscore, so my question is:

How do I auto-replace spaces with Underscores in PHP?

Answer (score 423, accepted):

```
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
```

Answer (score 78):

As of others have explained how to do it using `str_replace`, you can also use regex to achieve this.

```
$name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $name);
```

Comment: This is a better solution in the sense that it replaces multiple spaces with a single underscore which is usually the desired output.

Comment: Also tabs and whatever

Answer (score 27):

```
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 17):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function of PHP.

Something like:

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '_', $str);
```

Answer (score 11):

Call http://php.net/str_replace: `$input = str_replace(' ', '_', $input);`

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this to prevent the words from beginning or ending with underscores like _words_more_words_,  This would avoid beginning and ending with white spaces.

```
$trimmed = trim($string); // Trims both ends
$convert = str_replace('', '_', $trimmed);
```

Comment: This is interesting, as spaces in the start/end of the line will not get replaced by _ but instead removed. Though, mind that it may/will also strip other characters from the begin/end of the string as (\r and \n or tabs).

Answer (score 7):

Use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
str_replace(" ","_","Alex Newton");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Strtr` replaces single characters instead of strings, so it's a good solution for this example.  Supposedly `strtr` is faster than `str_replace` (but for this use case they're both immeasurably fast).

```
echo strtr('Alex Newton',' ','_');
//outputs: Alex_Newton
```

Comment: Cool, if one was to convert spaces to "_" in a multiple, lengthy files (logs?) this could be measurably faster? (Though there's no proof/reference, it may be an interesting answer for anyone interested in execution speed).

Comment: Hey Paul, I would think so. Try it and benchmark it.

Answer (score 0):

I used like this

```
$option = trim($option);
$option = str_replace(' ', '_', $option);
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` - it is evident solution. But sometimes you need to know what exactly the spaces there are. I have a problem with spaces from csv file.

There were two chars but one of them was 0160 (0x0A0) and other was invisible (0x0C2)

my final solution:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\xC2\xA0+/', '', $str);
```

I found the invisible symbol from HEX viewer from mc (midnight viewer - F3 - F9)

Comment: What about `'/\s+/'` ?