# Remove File extension and underscore

Tags: php

Is that possible to remove the file extension type from file name and underscore? For example: File name is MTK_USB_All_v1.0.1.zip But I want to show it as

> MTK USB All v1.0.1

Ex: https://androiddatahost.com/upload/Amomp

Right now Im using

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```

to show the file name. I also want to show the alternate name of the file without file extension and underscore.

Is that possible?

Comment: Is the file extension always `.zip`?

Comment: And of [Replace spaces with underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431051/replacing-spaces-with-underscores).

Comment: No, not always. But I want to strip the extension name for all the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$filename=basename($pathinfo);
$final_filename=str_replace('_','',$filename);
```

Comment: I think you meant to replace by a space, otherwise the result will be the filename with everything written together.

Comment: Tried both <?php echo $filename=basename($pathinfo); ?> and <?php echo $final_filename=str_replace('_','',$filename); ?> BUT its not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

To Show only the Filename you can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
$filename = pathinfo('filename.zip', PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

To replace underscore with blank space you can use str_replace();

Comment: Bro, Im a noob. I hv tried adding the code <?php echo $filename = pathinfo('filename.zip', PATHINFO_FILENAME); ?> offcourse it did replace the .zip extension from the filename. But instead of showing the file name it is only showing "filename". See example: alternate name -> https://androiddatahost.com/upload/RXRx5

Comment: If file name is 15_Second_ADB_Installer_v1.4.3.zip then I want to show 15_Second_ADB_Installer_v1.4.3.

Comment: Can you paste here the line of code you have written?

Comment: Have you changed the filename.zip to $name?

Comment: I have written this <?php echo $filename = pathinfo('$name', PATHINFO_FILENAME); ?> but thats not working.

Comment: This worked for me <?php echo $filename = str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '', $name)); ?> but there is full stop after file name. how to remove full stop

Comment: use rtrim($filename,".");

Comment: Is that possible for you to write the full code? Like <?php echo $filename = str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '', $name)); ?>

Comment: <?php $filename = str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '', $name));
echo $filename = rtrim($filename,".");
?>

Comment: Worked for me. !! Thanks alot.