# how to replace space with _ in php

Tags: php, mysql, url, request, record

i have add some values to mysql with a space
"bothof klimaattechniek"
"barth installatietechniek"
when i request it for a url then i only get the text in front of de space not the last part

how can i fix this ?

THIS IS THE URL I USE

```html
echo '<td><a href=\opdrachtgever_klant.php?opdrachtgever=';
echo $row['opdrachtgever']; 
echo ">";
```

[AND THIS IS WHAT I SEE ON MY URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYuGm.png)

[AND THIS IS WHAT MY VALUES ARE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtwE8.png)

Comment: I think you need to `urlencode()` the link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing Spaces with Underscores](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431051/replacing-spaces-with-underscores)

Comment: @Zl3n yeah i found that but i dont no how to add this in my current script :S

Comment: You also forgot the double quotes around the link, that didn't help...

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the url is not the problem that works fine the only thing thats not working as i like to is the value that it shows from database - it shows "bothof" but the value from mysql is "bothof klimaattechniek" i want the if i add a record by a form that spaces replace by _ and when i request it for display that  the _ will be replace by space and if i request value it will stay _

Comment: No it doesn't work, you just told us what the problem was. There's a space in your link, how is the browser going to distinguish between a space in your link and the start of a new html attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
{   $link = urlencode($row['opdrachtgever']);
        echo '<tr><td>'. $row['id']. '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['opdrachtgever']. '</td>';
  echo '<td><a href="opdrachtgever_klant.php?opdrachtgever='.$link.'">';
        echo 'Overzicht</a></td>';
```

i edit the code you gave me now it works perfect thanks :)

[see screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT36K.png)