# Replace space between two words with a -

Tags: php

I have a variable that contains two words

```
<?php echo htmlencode($record['countrythingy']) ?>
```

how can i replace the space in that specific variable with  a -

cheers

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: [`$record['countrythingy'] = str_replace(' ', '-', $record['countrythingy']);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: thank you i will use this and read the tutorials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing Spaces with Underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431051/replacing-spaces-with-underscores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$record['countrythingy'] = str_replace(' ', '-', $record['countrythingy']);
```