# Replace spaces with a Underscore in a URL

Tags: php

Replace spaces with a Underscore in `<?= $gr->grp_name ?>`

```
    <div class="groupinfo">
                    <a href="<?= base_url() ?>group/group_id/<?= $gr->grp_id ?>/<?= $gr->grp_name ?>">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing Spaces with Underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431051/replacing-spaces-with-underscores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str_replace` for replace space with underscore

```
<div class="groupinfo">
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>group/group_id/<?= $gr->grp_id ?>/<?= str_replace(" ","_",$gr->grp_name) ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Please close under-researched duplicate questions.  Stackoverflow doesn't need new pages that have already been solved elsewhere in the same community.

Answer (score 0):

You could use str_replace() function.

Comment: Please close under-researched duplicate questions.  Stackoverflow doesn't need new pages that have already been solved elsewhere in the same community.